# Why does Seebeck coeffcient increase with Temperature?

Tags: temperature, semiconductor-physics

So I have extracted a graph for the Seebeck coefficient vs energy with at varying temperatures (Top right). However, I am struggling to understand the relationship. Why is it the increase in temperature results in an increase in the Seebeck coefficient?

Higher temperatures should decrease transport distribution thus decreasing the Seebeck coefficient. For the approximation of S, the equation is **S = (E-Ef) / (kB*T)** showing S is inversely proportional to the temperature. What am I missing here? [image]